# C# how to sorted the Keys in Hashtable

Tags: c#

I have done reading a file and using the hashtable to sort the file, but the key is not in order.

example keys:

[WConning001]

[Paths]

[GeneralConfiguration]

[WWind001]

......

how to make the keys in order.?

Comment: Please prodive some code. Currently it's not clear what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

You should use `SortedDictionary<TKey, TValue>`. This provides keys sorted.

Here is link to [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f7fta44c(v=VS.100).aspx)

Answer (score 1):

Hashtables aren't meant to sort, if you want sorted Key/Value then use a `SortedDictionary<K,V>`

or you could use `LINQ`

```
var sorted = list.OrderBy( o =o.Value);
```